# Outlooks 2010 - multiple inboxes feature

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to configure Outlook to act sort of like Gmail multiple inbox feature.

I receive emails from task tracking system and filter them in separate folder. I would like to see them at the same time I see regular emails. Any thoughts?

Comment: To clarify: you're using filters to move certain incoming messages to folders, but you want to see all your incoming messages in one list?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the **Unread mail** search folder.  Scroll down to the bottom of the folder list until you come to the search folders.  In there you should find **Unread mail**.  You can customize this (right click > Customize this search folder) to include and exclude folders as you see fit, but the basically the idea is to use this folder instead of Inbox for an overview of new messages.  You can add it to your Favorites to make it easier to find.